# Is there a Linux distribution with reproducible build system?

Tags: linux, security, distribution-choice, iso, reproducible-build

Something like Gitian for Bitcoin when several people independently build binaries and publish their checksums,

I found NixOS but it has only reproducible packages but I mean a whole iso image?

Answer (score 2):

Debian is not fully there yet, but is working towards it.
Progress tracker is here:

https://wiki.debian.org/ReproducibleBuilds

Answer (score -2):

Yes, Archinstall is a reproducible build system.

Comment: Links to support this answer will necessary to validate the information. The [arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Reproducible_builds) web site suggests that this is still in progress.